# search filter is not working on back key press in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

search filter is not working on backkey press. Is something i am doing wrong? suggest me a suitable approach

```
useEffect(() => {
let tdata = { columns: tableData.columns, data_source: [] }
if (searchInput) {
    if (tableData && tableData.data_source.length > 0) {
        const filterData = tableData.data_source.filter((item: any) => {
            return Object.values(item).join('').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
        })
        tdata.data_source = filterData
        console.log("tata", tdata)
        setTableData(tdata)
    }
} else {
    getTableGoData({});
}}, [searchInput])


const searchTable = (e: any) => {
    setSearchInput(e)
}
```

Comment: This question feels hard to understand to me, can you rephrase and add details?

Comment: So you mean pressing back key permanently disables the input?

Comment: if i write MKJ000089 it is working properly and if i start deleting the letters, filter is not happening on backkey press.

Comment: i think the problem is not not with the backspace key, the press on backspace will trigger the useEffect if you've set up your change listener correctly. The problem is when you filter and get an empty result which will cause the next time you press any key to not take effect because of this condition => `tableData.data_source.length > 0`. try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `onChanges={filterHandler}` on input field or `onBlur={}`?

Comment: onChange={searchtable}

Comment: This code does not function as intended. Please edit this answer.